# Why is this sed not working?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a text file name `coalitions.txt` and it looks like this:

```
Hadash left
Balad left
Raam_Taal left
Meretz left
Shas right
Habait_Hayehudi right
Haihud_Haleumi right
Yehadut_Hatorah right
Liberman right
Avoda left
Kadima center
Likud right
```

I want to print a list of the last words in each line, without duplicates. The output should be:

```
left
right
center
```

I know I can use many techniques like `tail` but I want to know why what I did isn't working... I tried this:

```
cat coalitions.txt | sed 's/.*[[:space:]]\+\([A-Z][a-z]\+\)/\1/' | sort | uniq
```

But it just prints the same list again, as if my `sed` did not work. Why is this happening?

Comment: If you find yourself asking "*Why is this sed not working?*" -- **hint:** It's probably not `sed`'s fault.

Comment: Shouldn't the output be `center left right` (sorted)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This here

```
[A-Z][a-z]\+
```

is "one of A-Z, followed by one or more of a-z". What you meant is probably `[A-Za-z]`, or even better and not susceptible to locale variations, `[[:alpha:]]`.

I would just extract the last word of each line like this:

```
sed 's/.*[[:space:]]\([^[:space:]]*\)$/\1/' coalitions.txt | sort -u
```

No need for separate `cat`, and `sort | uniq` is the same as `sort -u`.

Comment: @TopCaver It would work (at least in GNU sed), but it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the right tool for the job:

```
$ awk '!z[$NF]++ {print $NF}' coalitions.txt
left
right
center
```

Answer (score 0):

I think sed doesn't recognize + as a meta character for 1 or more. you may try this.

```
cat coalitions.txt | sed 's/.* \([A-Za-z][A-Za-z]*\)/\1/' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: `\+` is an extension to Basic Regular Expression recognized by at least GNU sed.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks. i tried on a mac machine it's not recognized, but on another linux machine, it is.

Comment: Your solution fixes the problem anyway, though, and is POSIX conformant.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat coalitions.txt | sed 's/.*\s\+\([A-Za-z]\+\)/\1/'
```

This seems to have worked.  Since I am on a windows I have to use `\s` instead of `[[:space:]]`.  But even if I just change the space and try:

```
cat coalitions.txt | sed 's/.*\s\+\([A-Z][a-z]\+\)/\1/'
```

It does not work.  The problem is that the character range must use a comma and not a separate bracket.  `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: You probably don't want the comma in `[A-Z,a-z]`, unless you actually want to match a comma.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work, but `[A-Z,a-z]` matches letters _and comma_, whereas it seems you meant just "letters", as in `[A-Za-z]`. No comma required.

Comment: lol.  I actually wanted to know why it does.  I agree with you after you said, but don't know why the comma didn't cause a problem.  I removed it from my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: The bracket expression matches whatever is in it. `[a-z]` matches all lowercase letters, `[a-z,]` matches all lowercase letters and comma, and `[a-z,A-Z]` matches all lowercase letters, comma, and all uppercase letters.